# transcend his craft?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does that phrase mean in this context?

It’s unclear exactly when Tom Hanks took on the de facto role of “America’s Dad,” but these days, it’s hard to deny that he’s earned the title. As one of the most beloved actors of his generation, Hanks’ effervescent influence has come to ***transcend his craft***.

Source : https://time.com/5777520/oscars-2020-tom-hanks/

Answer (score 1):

**His craft** is acting.  To **transcend** is to go beyond the limits of something.  Therefore, it is saying that Tom Hanks' general popularity and cultural influence has gone beyond the realm of acting.